Trouble adding new data to mysql database when using HTML form onsubmit to call a JavaScript function
I am trying to get the users Email address to add it to an existing mysql data base, previously I used this HTML and PHP code which works and does add the data to the database both on my server and locally when using XAMPP:
<form class="EmailList" id="EmailForm" method="post" action="process-form.php">
    <input id="EmailInput" type="email" placeholder="Enter your Email address" name="email" required> <!-- name="email" -->
    <button type="submit">Notify Me</button>
</form>

<?php
$email = $_POST["email"];

$host = 'localhost';
$dbname = "mydbname";
$username = "myusername";
$password = "mypassword";

$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    die('Connection Failed : '. $conn ->connect_error);
}

$stmt = $conn ->prepare("insert into Subscriptions (email) value (?)");

$stmt -> bind_param("s", $email);
if ($stmt -> execute()) {
    echo json_encode(['success' => true]);
} else {
    echo json_encode(['success' => false, 'error' => $stmt->error]);
}

$stmt -> close();
$conn -> close();

but it had the problem of changing the page to a white screen which was not what I wanted, so instead I changed the code to this:
<form class="EmailList" id="EmailForm" method="post" onsubmit="EmailSubmitForm(event)">
    <input id="EmailInput" type="email" placeholder="Enter your Email address" name="email" required> <!-- name="email" -->
    <button type="submit">Notify Me</button>
</form>
<script src="Scripts.js"> </script>

and added the following JavaScript code as well:
function EmailSubmitForm(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var email = document.getElementById("EmailInput").value;

    fetch('/process-form.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body:JSON.stringify({email: email})
    })
    .then(Response => {
        console.log(Response);
        if (!Response.ok) {
            throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${Response.status}`);
        }
        return Response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
        if (data) {
            console.log(data)
        } else {
            console.log('Empty Response Code 4560546045');
        }
    })
    .catch((Error) => {
        console.log('MyError:', Error);
    });
}

but for the life of me it doesn't work, it gives me the following error when I try to run it locally via XAMPP:
"Scripts.js:36 MyError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "
"... is not valid JSON
"
but when I host it on my server it gives me a completely different error:
"Scripts.js:23
{success: false, error: "Column 'email' cannot be null"}
error
:
"Column 'email' cannot be null"
success
:
false"
I would appreciate some pointers here and thank you for reading this.

"changing the page to a white screen" - that's what the POST action on the form submit returns.  Changing process-form.php to return HTML would have fixed your original issue.

Use the network tab in the browser tool to see exactly what is going back and forth.

@fdomn-m after a bunch of googling looks like that first suggestion does work, however it isn't exactly what I want, the JS route has more flexibility and that's why I want to use it, assuming I cant make it work.
I will check that other method momentarily

I suspect the two errors are symptoms of the same problem, just with different error handling in different environments.  In which case the second error is the actual underlying problem and the first error is just the AJAX code failing when the server responds with HTML instead of JSON (because of the underlying error).
When you used a standard HTML form, PHP could read form inputs like this:
$email = $_POST["email"];

However, when you switched to AJAX you also switched to sending a JSON request body instead of form-encoded data.  Since the data is being sent to the server in a different way, the server-side code would need to change to read that new input.
You can read the entire JSON body with something like this:
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

And get the specific field you're looking for from that object:
$email = $data->email;


Yep that fixes it.
I have like 2 days worth of experience in this field, what is the normal method of debugging a website with such a structure? anyway we can put breakpoints and check all the variables?
Also if possible, could you point me in the direction of some good resources to learn more in this field? Random Youtube Videos and ChatGPT can only take me this far!

@Xikto: For client-side debugging, rely on your browser's development tools.  There's a script debugger for breakpoints, etc.  There's a network tab for requests/responses.  There's a lot there.  For server-side, use an IDE that has a step debugger for PHP code.  And use meaningful logging output throughout your code for debugging on remote servers as needed.  As for learning resources, honestly your guess is as good as mine.  My PHP is very dated.  There's a ton out there, and it's an unfortunate reality that a lot of what's out there isn't very good.
